# Qt menu artifact when calling input dialog

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview

I am building a PyQt application which is supposed to receive mouse right-click drags on a QGraphicsView, draw a "lasso" (a line stretching from the drag origin to the mouse position, and a circle at the mouse position), and then, on mouse release, erase the lasso graphics and display an input dialog for the next part of the app.

For some reason, when I use the mouse to click "Ok" on the input dialog, a menu artifact appears on the QGraphicsView which contained the lasso. The menu artifact is a drop-down menu line that says "(*check mark*) Exit". Occasionally it may be the context menu for one of my custom QGraphicsObjects as well - but for whatever reason, calling the dialog and then clicking "Ok" results in an unintended right-click-like event on the QGraphicsView.

This only seems to happen when the last step before method return is the QInputDialog - replacing it with a pass or a call to some other method does not result in the artifact. I'd be very grateful to anyone with a clue to what is causing this problem!

Here's the minimal code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    # The app main window.

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        # Initialize window UI
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self, labelText=None):
        # Set user-interface attributes.

        # Set up menu-, tool-, status-bars and add associated actions.
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')

        # Create a menu item to exit the app.
        exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('icons/exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        exitAction.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)

        # Create the main view.
        self.viewNetwork = NetworkPortal()
        self.viewNetwork.setMinimumWidth(800)
        self.viewNetwork.setMinimumHeight(800)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.viewNetwork)
        self.show()


class NetworkPortal(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    # A view which allows you to see and manipulate a network of nodes.

    def __init__(self):
        super(NetworkPortal, self).__init__(QtGui.QGraphicsScene())

        # Add the CircleThing graphic to the scene.
        circleThing = CircleThing()
        self.scene().addItem(circleThing)


class CircleThing(QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    # Defines the graphical object.

    def __init__(self):
        super(CircleThing, self).__init__(-10, -10, 20, 20)

        # Set flags for the graphical object.
        self.setFlags(
                      QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable |
                      QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable |
                      QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges
                      )

        self.dragLine = None
        self.dragCircle = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        # Reimplements mouseMoveEvent to drag out a line which can, on
        # mouseReleaseEvent, form a new Relationship or create a new Thing.

        # If just beginning a drag,
        if self.dragLine == None:

            # Create a new lasso line.
            self.startPosX = event.scenePos().x()
            self.startPosY = event.scenePos().y()
            self.dragLine = self.scene().addLine(
                         self.startPosX,
                         self.startPosY,
                         event.scenePos().x(),
                         event.scenePos().y(),
                         QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
                         )

            # Create a new lasso circle at the location of the drag position.
            self.dragCircle = QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem(-5, -5, 10, 10)
            self.dragCircle.setPos(event.scenePos().x(),
                                   event.scenePos().y())
            self.scene().addItem(self.dragCircle)

        # If a drag is already in progress,
        else:

            # Move the lasso line and circle to the drag position.
            self.dragLine.setLine(QtCore.QLineF(self.startPosX,
                                                self.startPosY,
                                                event.scenePos().x(),
                                                event.scenePos().y()))
            self.dragCircle.setPos(event.scenePos().x(),
                                   event.scenePos().y())


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):

        # If the line already exists,
        if self.dragLine != None:

            # If the released button was the right mouse button,
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:

                # Clean up the link-drag graphics.
                self.scene().removeItem(self.dragLine)
                self.dragLine = None
                self.scene().removeItem(self.dragCircle)
                self.dragCircle = None

                # Create the related Thing.
                # Display input box querying for name value.
                entry, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(None, 'Enter some info: ',
                                            'Input:', QtGui.QLineEdit.Normal, '')

                return


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    newWindow = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: As an experiment, try calling the base-class method at the beginning of your implementation, i.e. `super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)`. You could also try calling `event.ignore()` before the base-class call as well. The idea is to let any default behaviour happen (or explicitly ignore it) before doing your own stuff.

Comment: No change when I call the base-class method, even with event.ignore() before it. I'm not entirely surprised, however, since the base class method was not producing these artifacts until I added the QInputDialog (and also, the "(*check mark*) Exit" artifact isn't anything I've seen before in the behavior of these views and graphics objects.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, self-contained example so that others can try to reproduce the problem? Otherwise, you're just forcing people to resort to guesswork.

Comment: Added a minimal example code - thanks @ekhumoro!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Also, I cannot see how that example could produce the artifacts you mention, since the menus are created by your own application, and not by Qt. Are you running the code through some kind of IDE? If so, try running it as a stand-alone script in a console (or a command window, if you're on Windows).

Comment: Same here, @ekhumoro - no idea where these artifacts are coming from. I usually develop within the Atom IDE, but I tried running it from Windows console and the error persisted.

Comment: I can reproduce it with the example shown and from my experiments the issue is the `contextMenuEvent` getting an event with a weird `pos` (i.e. `(-9999, -9999)`).

Comment: Not-so-elegant-fix: If you do `event.accept()` in `contextMenuEvent` of the `QGraphicsView` subclass, that stops the menu from popping up. FWIW, the menu shown is the context menu from the `QMainWindow`.

Comment: Thank you @Avaris, that gets rid of the artifact! Just one problem - there are right-click context menus for some of the other objects that appear in that QGraphicsView subclass, and with the solution above, they are now suppressed! Is there a way to only pass through "approved" mouse release events (those associated with the graphics object subclasses I've specifically created for this program?)

Comment: The "Exit" menu is actually produced by the *toolbar*, and has nothing to do with the `QAction` (which, confusingly, is also titled "Exit"). So, contrary to what I assumed in my previous comment, the artefacts **do** come from a menu created by Qt. But presumably the weird `pos` from the spurious right-click event could potentially trigger *any* context menu in the application.

Comment: @Grav, yeah, that's the 'not-so-elegant' part. I also found out that `event.globalPos()` reports correct value which makes it doubly odd. But also gives me an idea for a workaround. You can compare `self.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())` with `event.pos()` in your view subclass and `accept/ignore` accordingly. BTW, for some reason, return value of `self.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())` is off-by-one (i.e. returns (3, 4) when the correct one was (4, 5)). Still not perfect, but maybe better.

Comment: Another (and maybe even better) workaround is to use `QTimer.singleShot(0, ...)` to spawn the input dialog. This will let the regular event chain complete before opening the dialog and prevent it from messing the events. This might change the logic of your code a bit but ultimately it could be the better solution.

Comment: @Avaris, that worked like a charm! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was not a direct answer to the cause of this bug, but using a QTimer.singleShot() to call the dialog (in combination with a QSignalMapper in order to enter parameters) is a functional workaround that separates the dialog from the method in which the bug was occurring. Thanks to @Avaris for this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess on my part, but I've seen this kind of weird thing before.

Some Qt widgets have default behavior on certain types of events.  I've never used QGraphicsView, but often the default for a right click is to open a context-sensitive pop-up menu (usually useless, in my experience).  That may be happening in your case, which would explain why you only see this when there's a right click.

You can suppress the default Qt behavior by calling `event.ignore()` before returning from `mouseReleaseEvent.`

Comment: I wish that was the case,@Paul_Cornelius! Unfortunately adding an event.ignore() before the return (or anywhere else in the method) doesn't fix the problem...